# afnetworking cache request to disc

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, afnetworking-2

I'm currently using the code below to load data from a webservice (over https).

I need a way to cache this data to disc.

Ideally the flow would be like this.

Has data loaded?

- If no - read from cache
- If no internet connection - read from cache
- If yes - continue as normal

How would this be possible?

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:@"someurl" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

To write the data to a file, you could `NSJSONSerialization` to convert your response object into `NSData`, then save the data to a file:

```
NSString* filePath [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"someFile.json"];
NSData* data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:responseObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
[data writeToFile:filePath options:0 error:nil];
```

Then, before you make the request, check if the file exists and read from it instead of doing your request:

```
NSData* jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
if(jsonData == nil){
    // Perform network request
}else{
    id responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
}
```